# How to refer bridges connecting two cycles?

Tags: graph-theory

I would like to ask how to refer bridges connecting two cycles in a graph. I don't know if there is a special name for it, but it would be practical in spectroscopy.

Comment: Just make up your own name for it. That's sort of traditional in graph theory; that's how there got to be so many different names for every concept: point, node, vertex; line, arc, edge; line graph, interchange graph, . . .